# Prove $|\cos(x+\sin 2x)|\leq |\cos x|$ holds for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

> Prove $$|\cos(x+\sin 2x)|\leq |\cos x|$$ holds for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

This is true, by WA graphing, but seems to be hard to prove.

Comment: It suffices to show this for $x\in [0,\pi/2]$ due to symmetry. Then you can discuss different cases. For instance, when $x$ is close to $\pi/2$, the inequality is $-\cos(x+\sin(2x))\leq \cos x$, that is, $\cos x + \cos(x+\sin(2x))\geq 0$, which is, $2\cos(x+\sin(2x)/2)\cos(\sin(2x)/2)\geq 0$, which is easy to see to be true.

Answer (score 1):

We need $$0\ge\sin^2(x+\sin2x)-\sin^2x$$

$=\sin(2x+\sin2x)\sin(\sin2x)=f(x)$(say)

Observe that $f(x)=f(-x)$

Now if $x>0,0<\sin2x\le1<\dfrac\pi2,\sin(\sin2x)>0$

We need to establish $0\le2x+\sin2x\le\pi$

The left inequality is obvious

So, we need $$\sin2x\le\pi-2x$$

Set $\pi-2x=z\implies\sin2z\le2z$

Use [How to prove that $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}x=1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75130/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-x-to0-frac-sin-xx-1)

Answer (score 0):

Note that
\begin{eqnarray}
f(x)&=&\cos^2x-\cos^2(x+\sin(2x)\\
&=&\frac{1+\cos(2x)}{2}-\frac{1+\cos(2x+2\sin(2x))}{2}\\
&=&\frac{\cos(2x)-\cos(2x+2\sin(2x)}{2}\\
&=&\sin(2x+\sin(2x))\sin(\sin(2x)).
\end{eqnarray}
From this, one can see that $f(x)$ is a periodic function with period $\pi$.

Case 1: $x\in[0,\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac12]$. Then $\sin(2x)\in[0,1]$ and
$$ 0\le2x+\sin(2x)\le\pi-1+1=\pi$$
and hence $\sin(2x+\sin(2x))\in[0,1]$. So $f(x)\ge0$.

Case 2: Similarly for $x\in[\frac{\pi}2+\frac12,\pi]$, $f(x)\ge 0$.

Case 3: $x\in[\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac12,\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac12]$. Let $t=x-\frac{\pi}{2}$ and then $t\in[-\frac12,\frac12]$. So
$$ f(x)=\sin(2t-\sin(2t))\sin(\sin(2t)) $$
is an even function. One only can consider $t\in[0,\frac12]$. Since
$$ 0\le 2t-\sin(2t)\le 2t\le1 $$
one has $f(x)\ge0$.